# InPlace Character animation plays abruptly when the character is moved in React Three Fiber

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, graph-editor

I have an inplace walk animation for a character, the animation plays well in blender (see below gif) but when the character is moved using code in React-Three-Fiber it moves abruptly as you can see in the below gif.

When I try out the same with [mixamo animations](https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&type=Character) in React-Three-Fiber they move smoothly, so I am of the opinion that the issue is with the animation, I am not sure where the issue is.

**Character Moving Abruptly in React-Three-Fiber**

[image: CharacterMovingAbruptly]

**Character Moving smoothly in Blender**

[image]

**Character Graph editor view**

[image: Character Graph editor view]